# If a function f is a rule, then how is it possible to represent it with a set of (input,output) pairs??

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Lately I have been trying to really understand functions and the notation that is used. I’ve been told over and over that $f$, a function is a rule like squaring, adding one, or taking the log. From what I understand,the domain is the pool of numbers that $f$ can be applied to, and $f(x)$ is the output. And in respect to the value of $x$, it will take on a different value.

I kind of see $f$ as just an operation that you can apply to a certain set of numbers, and as a result, there is a certain pool of values that it maps $x$ to, which I call $f(x)$.

So, how can an operation be represented by a set of points or a graph. It just intuitively seems wrong to call an operation anything other than it is. From this, it also doesn’t make sense how we can call something like $f(x)=x+1$ a function if it is actually just a formula for the output in respect to an input value $x$.

The ambiguity just frustrates me, and I would be very happy if someone could help me grasp this.

Comment: Mathematicians since Euler thought of functions as a *rule* for a hundred years before the modern definition in terms of ordered pairs was invented.  If you want to understand what a function is, you certainly should think in terms of a *rule*.  Once you convince yourself that in specific examples such as those you mentioned, this is compatible with the definition in terms of ordered pairs, you will be well on the way to understand the modern viewpoint which is more general.

Comment: Thank you. Though how should I go about thinking about it as a set of ordered pairs? 

If you search up “domain and range diagram” that is what is causing my confusion. F is the rule being applied to the numbers in the domain to get the output, but how can f, a rule be shown as a set of ordered pairs.

Comment: You may be conflating two things: a _rule_ (which is just an instruction how to get $f(x)$ given $x$) and a _formula_ (a writing using mathematical symbols representing an expression that you can calculate from a parameter, say $x$). The notion of _rule_ is wider and actually matches the modern definition of function as a set of ordered pairs. Namely, a rule can be a list: $$\begin{array}{c|c}x&f(x)\\\hline1&7\\2&42\\3&7.11\\\vdots&\vdots\end{array}$$ with arbitrarily populated second column, not all rules have a corresponding formulae, but this does not make them less of _rules_.

Comment: @Yk0902, consider the example you mentioned: $f(x)=x+1$, and let's assume for simplicity that $f$ is a function from the natural numbers to the natural numbers.  Then we can identify $f$ with the set of input-output pairs: $(1,2)$, $(2,3)$, $(3,4)$, etc.

Comment: @MikhailKatz, but is that not just describing that when f takes 1, the output is two; when f takes 2 the output is three etc? Is f not the thing that happens between them?

Comment: @Yk0902, you are absolutely right: in the modern viewpoint, the "thing that happens between them" gets lost in the shuffle.  If you just list the ordered pairs, it is not always clear what the original rule is.  But the transition to the set-theoretic definition in terms of ordered pairs is necessary to do modern analysis, where more general functions are envisioned than those prescribed by a rule that one can write down.

Comment: True, we don't track what happens between them. As long as the output is identical for identical input, this is the same function. Say, $f(x)=|x|$ is the same function as $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2}$.

Comment: What would be an alternative? In your sense, a "rule" would be something that someone can apply, an _algorithm_, There _is_ that notion in math (Computer Science) and it describes something, we just don't call it a "function". (A [computable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_function) may be a better term.) You can order alphabetically all algorithms and say $f(n)=\text{ result of }n\text{th algorithm }+1$. Which means that $f$ is not a computable function, yet I've given you a rule there. Where is the catch?

Comment: The catch is: there is no algorithm that can decide if something is an algorithm, in the first place! So the notion of "rule" as an "algorithm", even if it is close to everybody's heart and seemingly simple, is much more complex and intricate than you think!

Answer (score 1):

I perfectly understand your frustration, but I can tell you it is a "good kind" of frustration because it gives you the opportunity to pause, reflect and digest one of the most important mathematical concepts out there: functions.

I am not an expert, but I would like to share with you my understanding. Another good starting point may be the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)) about functions.

Intuitively speaking, we may look at a function as a kind of dynamical process that takes an input, manipulates it, and gives back a **unique** output.

If this intuitive picture is clear, we may ask how many symbols do we need to make the idea precise.

Of course, we need a symbol for the set of inputs that can be fed to our function. We use the symbol $D$, and call it the *domain* of our function. In general, it may happen that we have to work with different functions whose domains, albeit different, all lie in a common *input space*, say $X$. Clearly, the domain $D$ is always a subset of the input space $Y$.

Then, we require a symbol for the set of outputs that our function produces. We use the symbol $Y$, and call it the *output space* of our function.

Then, we need a symbol that indicates the transformation procedure associated with our function. We use the symbol $f$ and write $f\colon X\rightarrow Y$ or $X\stackrel{f}{\rightarrow} Y$. Moreover, when the input $x\in D\subseteq X$ is processed through our function, we write $f(x)\in Y$ for the output we obtain.

At this point, we condense our discussion saying that a function is a quadruple $(D,X,f,Y)$. Quite often, we just write $f$ to specify a function, and this is at the heart of all the confusion. Indeed, we can use only $f$ to specify a function if and only if the sets $D,X$, and $Y$ are clear from the context. Indeed, it is clear that the rule $f$ alone is not enough to specify a function because we must know what type of inputs we can use, and what type of output we should expect, otherwise, our knowledge of a function is incomplete.

Of course, sometime it is easier to write just $f$ because we are quite confident that whoever is reading our text is aware of who $D,X$ and Y are. However, this practice should be adopted only when a good introductory understanding of function has been obtained.

Now, for every $x\in D$, we may build a unique $y=f(x)\in Y$ simply applying our function to $x$. Therefore, we obtain a couple $(x,y)$ where the input $x$ is in the domain $D$, and the output $y\in Y$ is $y=f(x)$. If we are familiar with the notion of [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) between two sets, we can say that the function $(D,X,f,Y)$ determines a subset $\mathrm{graph}(f)\subseteq X\times Y$ given by
$$
\mathrm{graph}(f)=\{(x,y)\in X\times Y\mid\;\; x\in D, \;y=f(x)\}.
$$
The subset $\mathrm{graph}(f)$ is of course determined by the function $(D,X,f,Y)$, and it is called the *graph* of $f$.

There are situations in which the rule $f$ is associated to procedures we know very well, like squaring, adding 2, or taking square root of numbers. In these cases, we can write $f(x)=x^{2}$, or $f(x)=x+1$, or $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ to describe the actual rule with which our function transforms inputs in outputs, but it should be now clear that these expressions are not enough to specify a function.

Answer (score 1):

The function as a rule is an abbreviation, a shortcut in notation. A function is formally a specific relation. A relation is a subset of $D\times C$ where $D$ is the domain and $C$ is the codomain. So all starts with what you call pairs of input and output values. What specifies a relation as a function is the fact, that no two pairs with different output values for the same input value are allowed. However, instead of writing
$$
f=\{(x,y)\,|\,x\in D\wedge y\in C\}\quad (*)
$$
we write $f\, : \,D\rightarrow C$ and $f(x)=y.$ It is a convention and we are so used to it, and we can capture it faster than the notation as a relation, i.e. as a subset of a direct product of sets. In addition, we cannot see that $(*)$ is a function and not an arbitrary relation, but we automatically may assume that $f(x)=y$ defines a function because of the specific notation.

Summary: the set of pairs is the formally correct approach, and the rule is the convenient one.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that the OP has lost access to this account and cannot provide feedback to this answer, hope I will still manage to address their concerns. I will summarise what I said in my comments above.

The notion of a *function as a graph* is the currently "accepted definition of a function in maths", so to speak. It provides a solid definition on top of the set theory. (Whether this will remain in the following centuries is yet to be seen.) There is a small ambiguity still among different authors:

- Some authors define a function as a plain graph, i.e. a function $f:X\to Y$ is a subset of $X\times Y$ such that for every $x\in X$ there is exactly one $y\in Y$ such that $(x,y)\in f$.
- Some authors define a function as a *triplet* $(X,Y,f)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are sets and $f\subset X\times Y$ such that for every $x\in X$ there is exactly one $y\in Y$ such that $(x,y)\in f$.

The second definition has one advantage over the first, namely that it captures the notion of *codomain* (where the first definition can only capture the notion of *range*). But for all practical purposes you can choose either of those definitions.

Now you are saying that this definition captures only the *result of applying a function*, not the function itself. I guess that you think that the function "should" be a "rule" that somehow "crunches" the input and "produces" the output, and that "rule" gets lost if we accept the above definition.

This is true: the "rule" does get lost, and, for example, the functions $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ given by $f(x)=|x|$ and $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ given by $g(x)=\sqrt{x^2}$ are one and the same function: $f=g$. Even though two different "rules" were applied.

It turns out that in most applications you can ignore that "problem" and just treat functions as their graphs. In fact, even if we defined functions as something else, we would still need to "make equal" those which behave identically with respect to inputs and outputs: we would certainly need the notion that two functions are, well, maybe not the same, but *equivalent* if their graphs are identical. But for most uses of the word "function", this would be akin to nitpicking, because in most applications we really care about the *values* of the function rather than the original rule. Besides, if you have a graph of a function, that graph by itself is a sort of a "rule" how to calculate the values: just look them up in the graph!

The second and more important reason why we decide to not identify the functions with the "rules" is that the notion of a "rule" is extremely, I wouldn't say vague, but at least non-elementary. What counts as a "rule", i.e. the "thing that grabs the input and produces an output"? Is it an *algorithm*? Then we come to discussing what an algorithm is! Surely you don't want things like "take the input, but output the number of particles my Geiger counter recorded in the next 1 sec".

There are formal notions of algorithms (look up Turing machine), but all of them are finite (in the sense that they can be written using finitely many symbols), and so they can be enumerated (e.g. first by length and then lexicographically). Now look at this: say let $A_n$ be $n$th algorithm that produces a function $\mathbb N\mapsto\mathbb N$. What about the function $f(n)=A_n(n)+1$? This maps $\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ but is none of $A_n$. How is that possible? It is because $A:n\mapsto A_n$ itself is not an algorithm. Which means *there is no algorithm that can decide if something is an algorithm or not*.

And, even if this is not a final blow to the attempt to define a "rule", this is to show that it is a very non-elementary concept which one should not use as a basis for the definition of something as ubiquitous as a "function".

P.S. As a side note, have a look at [What colour are your bits](https://ansuz.sooke.bc.ca/entry/23). It is a very exciting article, and in the context of your question it implies that the attempt to put "rule" into a definition of a "function" is an attempt to bring our messy human world into maths, completely contravening the attempt of maths to make sense of our messy human world. One and the same function, which is $f(x)=0$, can be produced by three different ways, at least. One is just, you know, it is zero whatever the $x$. The other is my Geiger counter above, but enclosed in a lead box so that no particles ever come to it. A third one is *copyrighted* and you cannot use it without paying royalties: it is famous John Cage's composition [4'33"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yoAbXwr3qkg) which consists of 4 minutes 33 seconds of total silence.